# How to get list of JSON from the Http Get request in Java?

Tags: java, rest

I have a url which returns a JSON response & below is the code for that:

```
    String usepass = "XXXXXX" + ":" + "XXXXXXx#";
            String basicAuth = "Basic "
                    + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(usepass.getBytes());


            String url = "http://XXXXXXX/jira/rest/api/2/issue/CQ-12836?expand=changelog";

            URL obj = new URL("http://XXXXXXX/jira/rest/api/2/issue/CQ-12836?expand=changelog");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            // optional default is GET
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            //add request header
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
             String inputLine;
             StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
             while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
              }
             String jsonRespose = response.toString();
             in.close();
             //print in String
             System.out.println("*****print json*****");
```

But, now if change the url that returns a list of the JSON instead of single JSON then how can i handle that in java? What changes i have to make here?

Please help me here.

Comment: I think you can still see the output as you are reading it as a string

Comment: @ViharManchala is right.  All you do is print the response, you don't turn it into an object of some sort.  This code should work just fine.

Comment: @Carlos, Vihar - Thanks for your answers ;) But let's say if i change the url that returns a list of JSON or multiple JSON and i want to save & iterate all JSONs one by one to check some value inside the JSON then the same code will work?

Comment: Ah, no, that won't work.  You'll need to create a POJO and use some sort of mapper (Jackson works well) to map the list of JSONs to that POJO.  From there, you can properly iterate and inspect your array of objects.

Comment: @Carlos - Can we use list of Object class to get the list of JSONs?

Comment: It is very easy in Groovy, if you want to do it in Java then you have to convert it to POJO

Comment: @Ajay, Going by your comment in where you want to check some values within a JSON then the proper way to do it is to map it to a proper POJO.  If you want to just go by the simplest possible way then you would need to map the `String` version of your JSON payload to a `JsonNode` and from there you would be able to `get()` values based on a given property.